# no info and debug messages in Titanium console after updating Xcode

Tags: titanium

I'm using simple Ti.API.log() calls in several apps, and they worked fine - until I did the most recent XCode update. Since then, the Titanium console messages end with "focusing app simlatur" when I start an iOS App in the simulator, otherwise, no messages from my Ti.API.log() calls are displayed.

Run configuration -> log level is set to "info". Does anyone else have such problem or a solution?

Comment: Did you try clean whole project and build it again?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Funny enough, a collegue of mine now has the same problem. I went back to a previous version of XCode using Time Machine, then it worked again. After that, I updated to XCode 5.0.2 again and now the console still works - for me, but not for my collegue. I asked him to delete the "build" folder of the App, we'll see if that helps.

Comment: no, project -> clean and removing the build directory does not help. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug with the new version of the iOS simulator. See the issue tracker thread: 
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-15569

Scrolling down in that thread will show the current workaround reproduced below. This will download and install the newest bleeding edge version of the sdk that contains the fix. They estimate that it will be merged into an official release by mid december. If you are working in titanium studio, you might have to update to the newest version of that as well. I had this issue last week and fixed it by performing the below command and updating titanium studio. (titanium studio can be updated through help->install software and then adding the site for the beta release [see - http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/ ])

My new working setup is:

Studio version: 3.1.5.201311130103
CLI version 3.2.0
Titanium SDK version 3.2.0.v20131114123518

```
sudo npm install -g git://github.com/appcelerator/titanium.git
ti sdk install -b master -d
```

To get back to stable:

```
sudo npm install -g titanium@3.1.2
ti sdk select 3.1.3.GA
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue at the moment with 3.1.2.GA CLI. It has been fixed in the upcoming 3.2 CLI. Just hang in there while the AppC team works on this.

For the time being, you can uninstall the current cli via npm like so

```
    npm remove titanium
```

Then install the "latest and greatest" version from github like so

```
    npm install -g [sudo] npm install -g git://github.com/appcelerator/titanium.git
```

You can refer to the setup options here: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium